# Ensure that Python CLI matches version set in requirements.txt

Tags: python, dependency-management, requirements.txt

I'm co-developing a CLI for https://pretextbook.org/ authors. When an author runs `pretext new` we generate boilerplate files for their new project, including a `requirements.txt` that matches the current version of the CLI. If the author updates their CLI package, their project's source files may no longer be compatible with the updated package. Is there a canonical way to parse a `requirements.txt` file and print out a warning that the CLI version being used does not match the version set in `requirements.txt`?

Comment: I assume your `requirement.txt` file looks like typical _pip_ one.  What's wrong with parsing it with regexp or even looking for line `pretext==1.2.3` and splitting by `'=='`?

Comment: The issue I'd see is if an author edits `pretext==1.2.3` to (say) `pretext>=1.2.3` or some other valid format for `requirements.txt`. But if there's no built-in way to read the requirements file, I suppose this is just a warning anyway: I can just `try:` to parse the requirements file, and warn the author if something unexpected kept me from doing so naively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I wanted to parse requirements file like *pip*, I'd use [pip-requirements-parser](https://pypi.org/project/pip-requirements-parser/), since *pip* itself can't easily be used as a library, and *pip-requirements-parser* claims to be as close to *pip* as possible.

On another hand, I don't think you need that at all.  If user is expected to edit requirements file, then you can't really deduce anything from these versions.

Consider this:

1. New project is created using *pretext* v1.2.3
2. `requirements.txt` contains `pretext==1.2.3`
3. User edits the file to make it `pretext>=1.2.3`
4. User updates *pretext* to v2.3.4
5. Project source is no longer compatible with *pretext*, but CLI version matches `requirements.txt` specification.

Hence you need another solution, like a dedicated `.pretext_project_version` file, so you can reasonably expect user to not confuse project requirements and compatible CLI version.  This would also simplify project versioning for yourself, because you'll have to bump that version only on incompatible changes, rather than encode logic like *"project v 1.0 is compatible with 1.5 and 2.0, but not 2.2"*